# What does it mean to 'provide' an API call?

Tags: terminology, databases, api-design

So I have a database pre-loaded with data related to food recipes and the assignment says:
'Provide an API call that allows us to specify an ingredient or set of ingredients and return full recipes containing those ingredients.'

I am not sure if this means to create a webpage with a search box that would allow the client to enter text, search, and display recipes from the search query?

Any good opinion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

An API is an Application Programming Interface. So it is intended for two progammmed component to communicate. It is not a Human-Machine Interface, hence does not involve a web page for communication.

In your question, it could be a subprogram (in whatever variant or language) that can be called, with ingredients spécified in some way, possibly as parameters or in some other way such as global variables. This subprogram would get the recipies and make them available to the caller program in some adequate way.

Getting more into specifics depends on the various constraints of the system being developed. So here it is up to you as only you know the details.